# Spark Structured Streaming- Is it possible to write the offset twice

Tags: apache-kafka, offset, spark-structured-streaming, kafka-topic, spark-checkpoint

I am using spark structured streaming to consume data from kafka topic and write the data into another kafka sink.

I want to store the offset twice - once when reading from the topic and stire the offset. 
Secondly- when writing the data onto output sink and write the offset, which is possible by giving checkpoint directory location ,

Is it possible to write the offset consumed during subscribing the topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [StreamingQueryListener](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/streaming/StreamingQueryListener.html). You can add the listener to your stream by

```scala
spark.streams.addListener(new StreamingQueryListener() {

  override def onQueryStarted(event: StreamingQueryListener.QueryStartedEvent): Unit = { 

    // insert code here to log the offsets in addition to Spark's checkpoint

  }

  override def onQueryProgress(event: QueryProgressEvent): Unit = {}

  override def onQueryTerminated(event: StreamingQueryListener.QueryTerminatedEvent): Unit = {}
})
```

Comment: Hi Mike,

Can you please provide me a sample code on the same?